# Behavior and behavior created views

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I've created a Behavior which creates a CompositeView and the CompositeView then creates ItemViews from a collection. The ItemViews have a few events attached to them. These views trigger an event via the Application.vent event aggregator. I then listen for the event ("click:unlink") in the Controller which created the original view that contains the behavior.

But I think I'm starting to see zombie events, at least I assume they're zombie events. When I click the link that triggers the "click:unlink" event, the function that triggers the event I'm only seeing that called once, but I'm seeing the function defined in the listener fired multiple times.

So my question, when a view defines behaviors and those behaviors create their own views,  When the original view is destroyed for whatever reason, do the views associated with the attached behavior also get destroyed? I added some onDestroy functions on the views created by the behavior, but I never see them called. Maybe I'm not understanding how behaviors are supposed to be used?

Comment: That's the realization I was starting to come to. If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it as it answers my question perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A behavior will not destroy any views it has created, the only way a view created by a behavior could be destroyed is if it was placed in a `region` which was either emptied or replaced with another view.